# ASP MVC method Application_Start() in ASP Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to execute some logic after application startup in ASP Core app.
In ASP MVC it's performed in Application_Start() Global.asax method.
How am I supposed to do it in ASP Core (in respect with best practice) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ....
    IMyEndpointService service = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IMyEndpointService>();
    var result = service.ExecuteMyMethod();
    ....

}
```

but it also depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you provide more information you can get to the point answer.